# How to separate rules array and execute functions from that array

Tags: javascript

I have a class for validation which have different validation functions.
Now what i am trying to do is make an object in another file and send all the validation data using a constructor.This constructor will receive an object that looks like this "rules[is_empty:value]". In this left part is function name and value is the value fetched from input field.Now how do I call the function and send the value as an argument.Also what should i do when there are functions that has more than one argument.

I have already tried using map method and split method but not able to access the function.

```
class Validator {
    constructor(rules) {
        let rule_obj = {}
        // rules[is_empty:value,has_valid_min_length:2;3]

    }
    /**this is to check if the field has an empty value or not */
    is_empty = (value) => {
        if (value == '' || value == null) {
            return true
        }
        else {
            return false
        }
    }

    /**this is to check if value has required minimum length or not */
    has_valid_min_length = (value, min_length = 0) => {
        if (this.is_empty(value)) {
            return false
        }
        if (value.length < min_length) {
            return false
        }
        else {
            return true
        }
    }

    /**this is to check if value has more characters than maximum length */
    has_valid_max_length = (value, max_length = 0) => {
        if (this.is_empty(value)) {
            return false
        }
        if (value.length > max_length) {
            return false
        }
        else {
            return true
        }
    }

    //this is to check if selected date is less than given limit
    is_before_min_date = (value_date, min_date) => {
        if (this.is_empty(value)) {
            return false
        }
        if (value_date < min_date) {
            return true
        }
        else { return false }
    }

    //this is to check if selected date is higher than given limit
    is_after_max_date = (value_date, max_date) => {
        if (this.is_empty(value)) {
            return false
        }
        if (value_date > max_date) {
            return true
        }
        else {
            return false
        }
    }

}
```

I want to call the function which is before ':' sign in the array and give that function argument which is in value that is at the right side of ':'.

Please help.

Comment: Your approach is weird, what's the point on passing your rules and values as a string that has to be parsed ? It works in some cases but it do not seems to be the right way. https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-feather-tjhpi

Comment: I am open to a different approach. I would really like to know if there is any other way to do this.

Comment: @Blitz Your sandbox coding is what I needed only thing I can not understand is what is  .every(Boolean)? Can you please explain what does it do?

Comment: @BhaumikBhatt Why not simply call the validation functions directly with the values, instead of constructing a `Validator` object?

Comment: Indeed, calling directly validation functions seems better. The `.every(Boolean)` is to ckeck that all values are truthy.

Answer (score 0):

You could send an object through the constructor...

```
x = {
      "is_empty": [0, 2, 2],
      "has_valid_min_length": [ [value, min_length], [value, min_length] ],
      "has_valid_max_length": [ [value, max_length], [value, max_length] ],
      "is_before_min_date": [ [value_date, min_date], [value_date, min_date] ],
      "is_after_max_date": [ [value_date, max_date], [value_date, max_date] ]
    }
```

and then in your constructor, set up a loop through the object and value arrays...

```
constructor(to_be_validated) {
        let validator_names = Object.keys(to_be_validated);

        for (let validator of validator_names) {
            let values = to_be_validated[validator];

            if (validator === "is_empty") {
                for (let value of values) {
                    this.is_empty(value);
                }
            } else if (validator === "has_valid_min_length") {
                for (let value of values) {
                    this.has_valid_min_length(value[0], value[1]);
                }
            } etc...
        }
    }
```

and then when you call the function, the methods should execute

```
let my_validator = new Validator(x);
```

I echo the comment(s) above. Wanting the approach and specific syntax of,

```
let my_validator = new Validator(rules[validator_name:values]);
```

all in one clean line like that, is a bit off. I've never seen it done like that.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want an additional function in your class that calls all the check-functions according to your rules.

```
class Validator {
    constructor(rules) {
        this.rules = rules;
        // rules={is_empty:[],has_valid_min_length:[2]};

    }

    validate = (value) => {
        let pass = true;
        Object.keys(this.rules).forEach(k=>pass = pass && this[k](value, ...this.rules[k]));
        return pass;
    }

    ...
}
```

The `rules`-Objects has key-value-pairs, where the keys are the function-names of the individual checks and the values are arrays of parameters that will be passed. This array can have zero or more entries.

**Edit:** `forEach` will iterate over all the keys. On every turn `k` will hold the current key. `pass` is a boolean that collects all the return values of your checker-functions. (`true && false === false`) That way the final return-value will be false if any of the checks returned false.

You would then apply the rules to your data like this:
`myValidatorObj.validate(data);`

Comment: Can you explain what value does this k and pass holds?

Comment: I edited the answer. There may very well be mistakes in my code and/or logic, but I hope you get the idea.